# Qual a diferença entre um plugin e uma biblioteca em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, front-end

Recentemente tenho estudado bastante front-end no mundo vasto que é a programação web e por instalar alguma funcionalidade nova nos sites que desenvolvi percebi que alguns autores chamavam seu projeto .js de biblioteca e outros de plugin.

Gostaria saber diferenciar um plugin de uma biblioteca e vice-versa.

Quanto a terminologia, qual a diferença entre plugin e biblioteca?

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente:

Um **PLUGIN** é um componente que adiciona funcionalidades a um programa existente (segundo a [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29))

Uma **BIBLIOTECA** é um conjunto de rotinas e métodos que podem ser usados para desenvolver software

Answer (score 1):

Em um contexto web, vejo esses dois termos sendo utilizados de forma diferente. Da definição:

1. O plugin é um tipo de **extensão intrínseca ao contexto**. Ela pode
   ser utilizada somente naquele contexto e não pode ser desplugada
   para colocar em outro. É como um plugin de navegador, pois irá
   funcionar somente naquele navegador. Ou um plugin para jQuery, que
   funcionará somente com o jQuery, e não sozinho.
2. Já a biblioteca é um tipo de **extensão agnóstica ao contexto**. Ela
   pode ser utilizada em qualquer lugar com um runtime JavaScript (ou
   até sem) e pode ser facilmente *desplugada* e colocada em outro
   contexto. Como se fosse um coringa. Um exemplo é o próprio jQuery,
   que funciona em qualquer contexto que tenha um motor JavaScript.

Assim sendo, podemos inferir que:

1. Um plugin **consome código ou APIs da aplicação principal**. As extensões de navegador consomem APIs do Chrome, por exemplo. Ou plugins jQuery consomem APIs do jQuery.
2. As bibliotecas **são consumidas pela aplicação principal**. Se você tem a biblioteca do jQuery, seu programa consome suas APIs, como `$('div').remove`.